# Как сделать плавный скролл вниз при нажатии на чекбокс?

Tags: javascript

Есть html-структура.
Необходимо, чтобы при активации чекбокса происходил плавный скролл до блока id="tabs-section" , который находится ниже.

```html
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">

<div id="tabs-section">
<!-- Тут контент -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плавную прокрутку легко реализовать с помощью метода элемента `scrollIntoView`.

Если этому методу передать аргументом объект параметров со свойством `behavior: 'smooth'`, то прокрутка будет плавной.
(по-умолчанию, значением behavior является `'auto'`)

```js
const cbox = document.querySelector('.linkinp'), 
      tabs = document.querySelector('#tabs-section'); 
cbox.addEventListener('change', evt => {
  if (evt.target.checked) 
    tabs.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' }); 
}); 

// генерация контента (типичного для интернета)
tabs.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p></p>'.repeat(50)); 
tabs.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p></p>'.repeat(50));
```

```html
<label>
  <input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
  Не хочу котиков
</label>

<div id="tabs-section">
  Тут контент
</div>
```

В параметрах также действуют свойства `block` и `inline`, значениями которых определяется место остановки прокрутки по вертикали и горизонтали, соответственно. У обоих свойств возможны следующие значения:

- `'start'` - верхний / левый край элемента
- `'end'` - нижний / правый край
- `'center'` - центр элемента
- `'nearest'` - ближайший край элемента к ближайшему краю контейнера с прокруткой

Comment: Скажите как Вы получили плавный скролл ?

Comment: происходит генерация контента  из-за этого скролл плавный ?

Comment: @user354190, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: @user354190, я дополнил ответ - дополнение отвечает на твой вопрос? И нет, наличие контента не имеет решающего значения - надо только чтобы было куда прокручивать :) Вместо "контента" можно было просто стилями сделать большой отступ, например.

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста, а как сделать,чтобы скрипт срабатывал при нажатии на любой чекбокс. Пока что только разбираюсь в JS, понял, что querySelector обращается к БЛИЖАЙШЕМУ элементу, а как сделать, чтобы срабатывал скролл вне зависимости от позиции?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/shBDYaqv

Answer (score 1):

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target;

if(target.tagName != 'input'.toUpperCase()){
  return
}
let div = document.querySelector('#tabs-section');

let divCoords = div.getBoundingClientRect();

if( target.checked ){
  window.scrollTo( {top: divCoords.y, behavior: 'smooth'}  )
} else{
  console.log( target.checked )
}

})
```

```css
#tabs-section{
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id='form'>
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
<input class="linkinp" type="checkbox">
</form>

<div id="tabs-section" >
Тут контент
Тут контент
Тут контент
Тут контент
Тут контент
Тут контент
</div>
```

1. Вот так ?
2. Как плавно сделать я не знаю ...

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов  исправил :)