# Как выбрать из списка (JS)?

Tags: javascript

мне необходимо выбрать из списка элементов и я не могу разобраться.

Вот моя жалкая попытка:

```js
var day = document.getElementsByClassName('ij_bday');
day.document.getElementById('selectedItems').value = 1;
```

Вот список из которого необходимо выбрать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что выбрать из списка элементов ?

Comment: Одну из цифр
Допустим: 2 или 4

Comment: где HTML код :?

Comment: @user354190, вот: 

https://i.imgur.com/rlPaAmn.png

Comment: по ссылке есть вопрос с html кодом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040948/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81/1040965?noredirect=1#comment1775610_1040965 Вы должны вставить в свой вопрос свой HTML код

Comment: @user354190, вот скриншот: https://i.imgur.com/rlPaAmn.png

Мне нужно выбрать на сайте vk.com из списка.

Comment: let d 

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(e){
    d = e.target.value;
    console.clear(d);
    console.log( d );
});

Comment: @user354190, выдало ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

https://i.imgur.com/3G7JCbN.png

Comment: берете класс или id в инпуте и вставляете document.querySelector('input')

Comment: что бы решить вашу проблему встав те код сюда